# Redirecionamento HTML

Tags: html5, div

Olá estou criando um calendário para um site meu de animes e gostaria de redirecionar cada `<div>` para um certo lugar. No caso eu fiz uma página assim:

[image: Página]

Gostaria que cada um levasse para uma página específica.

(Dúvida já esclarecida..)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/jSCKYV9.jpg  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.dia {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.dia h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}

.buttons {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.buttons * {
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendário 2018 - G1Animes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dia" id="segunda">
    <h1>Segunda-Feira</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="dia" id="terca">
    <h1>Terça-Feira</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="dia" id="quarta">
    <h1>Quarta-Feira</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="dia" id="quinta">
    <h1>Quinta-Feira</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="dia" id="sexta">
    <h1>Sexta-Feira</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="dia" id="sabado">
    <h1>Sábado</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <div class="dia" id="domingo">
    <h1>Domingo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Mas, não é só colocar links nas  `divs`.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, não é simplesmente adicionar um link para cada item?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu coloquei o href porem não está funcionando

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta, mas isso é algo muito básico... não adianta colocar o `href` na `<div>`, você precisa de um elemento `<a>` ou fazer o redirecionamento via javascript...

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_test

Comment: `<a href="seu link"><div class="dia" id="sexta"><h1>Sexta-Feira</h1></div></a>` vc precisa colocar uma tag de link envolta da sua div... É essa a dúvida?

Comment: @hugocsl kkk era isso mesmo obrigado :)

Comment: Que bom que resolveu, mas leia bem a resposta do @dvd pois ele fala de pontos que vão te ajudar muito no futuro. Não deixe de estudar os fundamentos evite só pegar coisas prontas. Boa sorte ai

Answer (score 0):

Vamos pensar inicialmente na estrutura centralizada responsiva e com links:

html:

```
<div class="box_wrapp">

    <a href="pagina1.html">         
        <span class="text">Segunda</span>   
    </a>

    <a href="pagina2.html">         
        <span class="text">Terça</span> 
    </a>

    <a href="pagina3.html">         
        <span class="text">Quarta</span>    
    </a>

</div><!-- /box_wrapp-->
```

css:

```
<style>
    body{
        text-align:center;
        font-family:trebuchet ms;
    }
    .box_wrapp{
        display:inline-block;
        width:300px;
        max-width:95%;
    }
    .box_wrapp a{
        display:inline-block;
        width:100%;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:10px 0 10px 0;
        margin:0 0 10px 0;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        color:#FFF;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .box_wrapp a:hover{
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    .box_wrapp span{
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Se vc tem conhecimento em jquery, e está querendo fazer um calendário, talvez o fullCalendar também possa ser uma boa idéia.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar links você deveria usar a tag `<a>` onde no atributo `href` você coloca a página destino para onde será direcionada a página ao clicar no link.

Para que tenha o mesmo formato que você fez usando `div`, é preciso adicionar alguns estilos ao `<a>` (cuja classe é `.dia` — *veja comentários no CSS*).

O uso do `<h1>` como fez também não é o correto. As tags `<hN>` (onde `N` vai de 1 a 6) devem ser usadas como cabeçalhos de textos, como você pode conferir **[nesta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)** ( me parece que você usou apenas para que o texto ficasse em negrito e para centralizá-lo).

Veja abaixo como fica usando as tags `<a>`. Basta apenas substituir os respectivos valores de cada `href` pela página para onde cada link levará ao ser clicado:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/jSCKYV9.jpg  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.dia {
   /* estilos adicionados (início) */
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold 30px "Comic Sans MS";
   /* estilos adicionados (fim) */

  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* removido
.dia h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
} */

.buttons {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.buttons * {
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendário 2018 - G1Animes</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="segunda.html" class="dia" id="segunda">
    Segunda-Feira
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <a href="terca.html" class="dia" id="terca">
    Terça-Feira
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <a href="quarta.html" class="dia" id="quarta">
    Quarta-Feira
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <a href="quinta.html" class="dia" id="quinta">
    Quinta-Feira
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <a href="sexta.html" class="dia" id="sexta">
    Sexta-Feira
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <a href="sabado.html" class="dia" id="sabado">
    Sábado
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <a href="domingo.html" class="dia" id="domingo">
    Domingo
  </a>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
</body>
```

> Não ficou claro o uso dessas `<div class="buttons">`. Se puder
>   esclarecer o seu uso talvez nem seja necessário também e podemos complementar na resposta.